# Should I keep or delete my own question (solution found) with no answers yet?

Tags: discussion, answers, specific-question

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Two javascript snippets using websockets were expected to be similar in behavior but they aren't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67362614/two-javascript-snippets-using-websockets-were-expected-to-be-similar-in-behavior)

A few hours after posting the question above, I had an idea and found that the problem was due to a typo I made in my code.

*My question hasn't yet received any answer* (at the time of this writing).

I wrote an answer (not posted yet) to my own question, but I would like to know if answering such a question (whose solution is just "fix a typo") is worthwhile, or should it be deleted instead?

Comment: If your problem and answer would be very helpful to others, keep it, and post a high-quality and adequately detailed answer that explains the source of the problem and how you solved it. If it's nothing more than a problem caused by a typographical error, then that is not likely to be helpful to future visitors, and then you probably should just delete it.

Comment: Your question looks mostly nice, at least it is well-formulated (apart from naming issues and some noise - I've edited the former and removed the latter + I would be very careful with listing several questions - although in your case they seem to be closely related, this style might trigger the "too broad" closure depending on who's on duty [read: notices your post]), keep it. It is either a duplicate (haven't analyzed it yet) or can be answered.

Comment: ^ ah, here it is already, ironic that it happened just as I was adding a section on multiple questions. Note that if the solution is *literally* a typo (in a typographical sense first and foremost, it may be better to delete the question). But if it is closer to a misunderstanding and can be addressed in good detail - then I see no problem with keeping it.

Comment: ^ with the above said, after looking over the code, I suppose the typo is in the wrong capitalization of the so-called "onevent" properties (because they are case-sensitive). If that's the case, it is likely to be closed as a typo.